# Why is my graphql Higher Order Component fire the options 11 times with the Apollo Client?

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm using apollo client in an exponent react native app and have noticed that the graphql options method gets run 11 times, why is that?  Is that an error or a performance problem?  Is that normal?  Is it running the query 11 times as well?

```
...

@graphql(getEventGql,{
  options: ({route}) => {
    console.log('why does this log 11 times', route.params);
    return {
      variables: {
        eventId: route.params.eventId,
      }
    }
  },
})
@graphql(joinEventGql)
@connect((state) => ({ user: state.user }))
export default class EventDetailScreen extends Component {
...
```

Looking at the sample from the documentation http://dev.apollodata.com/react/queries.html

> Typically, variables to the query will be configured by the props of
>   the wrapper component; where ever the component is used in your
>   application, the caller would pass arguments. So options can be a
>   function that takes the props of the outer component (ownProps by
>   convention):

```
// The caller could do something like:
<ProfileWithData avatarSize={300} />

// And our HOC could look like:
const ProfileWithData = graphql(CurrentUserForLayout, {
  options: ({ avatarSize }) => ({ variables: { avatarSize } }),
})(Profile);
```

> By default, graphql will attempt to pick up any missing variables from
>   the query from ownProps. So in our example above, we could have used
>   the simpler ProfileWithData = graphql(CurrentUserForLayout)(Profile);.
>   However, if you need to change the name of a variable, or compute the
>   value (or just want to be more explicit about things), the options
>   function is the place to do it.

Comment: Could it be that you have 11 events? How is your routes setup, when does the  `eventId` route param change?

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/exponent/ex-navigation that comes with react native exponent - using their standard starter boilerplate

Comment: Do you have 11 instances of the component, are any of the props changing in the wrapping component?

Comment: 1 instance of the component - something must be triggering the prop